# Store user as well as bot response in bot framework

Tags: botframework

I want to store the response received from bot as well as the message typed by the user in `bot framework v4`.

I have tried implementing the `ITranscriptLogger` and add it to the service configuration, is that the right way of doing it ? Also, the class implementing the `ITranscriptLogger` never gets called.

My intention is to save the whole conversation as it happened so that it can be reviewed later.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ITranscriptLogger` is only part of it. It's nothing more than an Interface. Once you build a logger that implements it, you need to add the [`TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs).

Your `ITranscriptLogger` should look something like this:

```cs
public class MyLogger : ITranscriptLogger
{
    public async Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        // Handle logging the activity...to a file or cloud service, etc
    }
}
```

Add the following:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
var logger = new MyLogger();
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(logger);
services.AddSingleton(transcriptMiddleware);
```

**AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs**

```cs
public AdapterWithErrorHandler(TranscriptLoggerMiddleware mylogger, ...) {
    [...]
    Use(mylogger);
}
```

Comment: This will only log the exceptions right ? Do I need to call the middleware everytime I need to log something ?

Comment: @AshishKumar That will log all activities, unless you put it under the `OnTurnError` part. You do not need to call it every time; `AdapterWitherrorHandler` receives all activities and forwards them to the logger.